# Plotting table from file in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I'm trying to plot some data using GNUplot. These data are being generated using a fortran software, and this is a very small excerpt of the code.

```
 Angle:            0  Radius:    3.00000012E-02  Intensity:    1.67673090E-04
 Angle:            0  Radius:    3.50000001E-02  Intensity:    1.67673090E-04
 Angle:            0  Radius:    3.99999991E-02  Intensity:    1.67673090E-04
 Angle:            0  Radius:    4.49999981E-02  Intensity:    1.67673090E-04
 Angle:            0  Radius:    4.99999970E-02  Intensity:    1.67673090E-04
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: What do you want to plot? And how? There is only 1 variable, so that won't give an interesting plot. Also, try to use headers and three columns, instead of six, i.e. `# Angle Radius Intensity`

Comment: Hello, sorry the late reply. I want to plot these values on a polar plot. Angle is variable and increases up to 180.

Comment: It is still not clear. It should become a contour plot?

Comment: yes. A 2D contour polar plot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this, assuming the data is in a file called tmp.txt:

```
set yrange [1e-4:2e-4]
set xrange [2.5e-2:5e-2]

plot "tmp.txt" u 2:3 'Angle: %lf Radius: %lf Intensity: %lf'
```

see 'help datafile using' and the paragraph at the end about scanf options.